# Is it better to use 2 controllers for the same page's two parts

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have one page which has two parts, both parts are somewhere dependent on each other. So my question is Do I need to create 2 different controllers for that.(if yes then how i will share the $scope between them) or just use one controller for both.

Comment: Why do you think about using 2 controllers ?

Comment: for separation of concerns, as we have two separate complex UI screens.

Comment: I think you need 3 controllers.
One parent, and 2 others for their respective part.

Comment: *"Do I need to"*  ... no that is subjective. Can share methods and data through a service if you do want to split them or nest them in a parent controller

Comment: Better to use 1 controller for 1 page, This will be easy to use and easy to maintain. If there are 2 different pages, then it make some sense  to use different controller.

Comment: @Samir one per page is not a practical config when re-using components. There is no way to generalize like that

Comment: It is better to use single controller and then move operations which belong to different part in service. It doesn't make sense to have different controllers for a single page if it is not shared between multiple pages.

Comment: If you're using a component-based approach each component/directive should have its own controller

Answer (score 1):

You could use either.

One controller and have the scope available to both parts of your page.

Two controllers and use a service. You will want to check in to .service and .factory to share data between controllers. An example of a service:

```
.factory('storageService', function () {
    var vars = [];
    var storageService = {};

    storageService.set = function (key, value) {
        vars[key] = value;
    };

    storageService.get = function (key) {
        return vars[key];
    };

    return storageService;
})
```

There are also directives which you can pass whatever you want from $scope into the directive. In html on your directive you would set an attribute called scope and pass it some variable defined in scope like...

```
<some-directive scope="data"></some-directive>

.directive('someDirective', ['$rootScope', 'storageService', function ($rootScope, storageService) {
    return {
        restrict   : 'AE',
        scope      : {
            scope: '=' 
        },
        replace    : true,
        templateUrl: 'some/path',
        link       : function ($scope, element, attr) {
            $scope.setResetValue = function(value){
                storageService.set('resetValue', value);
            }
        }

    };
}])
```